# Trap Error message in a function

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if I could trap error messages in to variables in a function and write it in to a log file. This is where I'm pretty stuck.

```
function ErrorMessage([]$errormessage){
    echo $errormessage >> logfile.txt;
    exit;
}
```

---

Here is what I have done up until now:

```
function ErrorMessage{
    Catch
    {
        $_ >> logfile.txt
        Exit 
    }
}

import-module 'MDTDB Script'
connect-mdtdatabase -sqlserver 'Server name' -instance 'instance' -database 'Database
$computersSQL = get-mdtcomputer

ErrorMessage
```

For example if the server is not reachable it would write the error message into the logfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should trap error messages in a catch statement. Here's an example:

```
Try
{
    This-Will-Throw-An-Error
}
Catch
{
    $_ >> logfile.txt
    Exit 
}
```

Comment: this will only trap terminating errors unless you change the `$ErrorActionPreference` to 'STOP' ...

Comment: You haven't provided detailed info as to what you're trying to achieve, but I think this could help you.
After running the a command which you suspect would throw an error, you can check the $? variable to see if the command executed successfully, if it didn't then you can take the last error from the built in $Error variable and log that. Hope that helps

Comment: @MusaabAl-Okaidi Technically I'm looking for a little function that writes down errors in to a log file (expected error would be 'Server not reachable') so that i don't have to write the whole script after every connection but just the name of the function

Comment: It would be better if you post the code that you're working with, that way myself or others on the forum would be able to help you more effectively.